# Has anybody been able to make a Custom Metadata Type record in the Salesforce UI?

Tags: custom-metadata

I am trying to create Custom Metadata Type records in my Developer Org (Winter 17) but the edit record page is blank. Upon hitting save, I get validation errors about missing fields.

My understanding is I should also be able to make these from my IDE but Mavensmate has been unable to pull my Custom Types.

[image]

Has anybody successfully been working Custom Metadata Types?

Comment: I am able to successfully create the custom metadata types in a developer org and edit the custom metadata type .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava have you been able to create records for that custom metadata type in the UI? I am seeing the same error as above where the record edit screen contains no fields, then validation errors are thrown on save.

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed to make it completely blank; it should have at least four fields on the screen you can't remove. Check your page layout and see if you can add the fields to the layout (Setup > Develop > Custom Metadata Types > (Label) > Page Layouts > Edit (Layout Name).

Comment: Does your CMT have a relationship field?

Comment: @sfdcfox There were no page layouts for the Custom Metadata Type and therefore no layouts were assigned for any profiles for the CMT.
Adding a layout and assigning it to the correct profile fixed the issue.

Comment: Did that resolve your issue? Would you like me to add this as an answer?

Comment: @Nico actually, perhaps you'd like to add an answer yourself? You could explain what happened and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

As @sfdcfox mentionned above, this issue had to do with the lack of page layouts for the Custom Metadata Type.

- The steps to fix this are the following: Create a page layout with
  all the necessary fields. (**Setup > Custom Metadata Types > View
  [MyCustomMetadata] > Page Layouts > New**)
- Assign the layout to the
  relevant Profiles. (**Setup > Custom Metadata Types > View
  [MyCustomMetadata] > Page Layouts > Page Layout Assignment**)